# SQLite - Generate tables with totals, but exclude duplicate entries from SUM

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with a SQLite spatial database that contains property ownership information for all parcels in the county. Among other things it contains fields for the parcel number(`PARCEL_NO`), acreage (`TOTAL_ACRE`), property value (`TOTAL_VALUE`), and owner (`OWNER`). Each record has a primary key called `OBJECT_ID`.

I am trying to generate a sorted (descending) list of all property owners in the county, ranked by how much property they own, both in acres and dollars.

I tried two queries to get this information:

**`SELECT OWNER, SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) FROM thurstonparcelsowners GROUP BY OWNER ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) DESC`**

**`SELECT OWNER, SUM(TOTAL_ACRE) FROM thurstonparcelsowners GROUP BY OWNER ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL_ACRE) DESC`**

The problem is that some larger parcels are broken up into multiple separate records with different `OBJECT_ID` but the same `PARCEL_NO`, `TOTAL_ACRE`, `TOTAL_VALUE`, etc. For example, in the map below, all of the yellow highlighted area is actually one large parcel with a single `PARCEL_NO`, but within the database is broken up into dozens of smaller map objects (the red selected area is one of these with the same `PARCEL_NO` as the other yellow features), each containing the same attribute values (PARCEL_NO = 12806410000, TOTAL_ACRE = 929, OWNER = EVERGREEN STATE COLLEGE, etc):

[image]

So when I run the queries above, the SUM counts each of these objects, making it where this 929 acre parcel registers as 20,000+ acres (because it was counted once for each record, rather than once per parcel number. How do I structure these queries so that the values for each PARCEL_NO are only counted once by SUM?

Thanks!

Comment: The above was intended to be sample data. The parcel with PARCEL_NO = 12806410000 has a TOTAL_ACRE of 929 and OWNER of Evergreen State College. There are however 23 separate records in the database, each of which has a different OBJECT_ID but the same TOTAL_ACRE, OWNER, and PARCEL_NO. When I sum the total acres for this owner (Evergreen State College) the result should be 929. However, because there are 23 records each of which has TOTAL_ACRE of 929, the queries above give 929*23 = 21367 acres owned by Evergreen State College, which is not correct.

Comment: ^ that was a response to someone requesting sample data ... but they removed their comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to remove the duplicates to turn it into unique parcel, owner, total acre and total value. This subquery will be your new table then run your query as usual.

For example:

```
SELECT OWNER, SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) 
FROM  (
     SELECT DISTINCT PARCEL_NO, TOTAL_VALUE, OWNER
       FROM thurstonparcelsowners
      ) t
GROUP BY OWNER 
ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) DESC;
```

You can do a similar query for total_acre.

Comment: This is how I interpret the problem description so getting the distinct values for parcel no, total value, total acre and owner is sufficient. To quote "The problem is that some larger parcels are broken up into multiple separate records with different OBJECT_ID but the same PARCEL_NO, TOTAL_ACRE, TOTAL_VALUE, etc. "

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Getting the correct results now.

Comment: Glad to help. Your post is also well written and easy to understand. Kudos.